# Arrays/Lists in the inspector of Editor Extension scripts

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, editor

strange issue here

I'm currently upgrading my Unity editor extension, Build Automator, and I need to assign an array or list of textures in the editor so that it can use them. The problem is, that the inspector for the script doesn't display the list or array, but works fine if its a singular Texture.

Does anyone know why this is, or how to get around it?

Comment: Have you made it `public` or marked it with [`SerializeField`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SerializeField.html)?

Comment: It's public yeah

Comment: May be you just try default array and in editor extension transform him to list?

Comment: Neither are working. I've resorted to loading the textures by using the asset database and their paths